# DPDK how to use rte_flow

Tags: c++, dpdk

I'm new to dpdk, please tell me if it's possible to bind multiple data_sender to a physical port?

At the moment I can process traffic and send it to a remote server via data_sender on one physical port (ip=192.168.2.1; listen_port = 7001;). But so i can handle 7gb/s, and it's not enough.

Is it possible to configure a network card so that it balances traffic internally and forwards traffic to one physical port, but to different sockets? (ip=192.168.2.1; listen_port1 = 7001;listen_port2 = 7002;)

1. Is it possible to use rte_flow for these purposes?
2. little example how to configure device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use multiple tx_queues and cores. Try reading the `rte_eth_dev_configure`, `rte_eth_tx_queue_setup`, and `rte_eal_mp_remote_launch`. Also go through [dpdk-l2fwd](http://doc.dpdk.org/guides/sample_app_ug/l2_forward_real_virtual.html)

Yes, you can use rte_flow. You need to specify some matching pattern of your traffic and then apply the `RTE_FLOW_ACTION_TYPE_SET_TP_DST` action.

You can have a look at the [dpdk-flow_filtering](http://doc.dpdk.org/guides/sample_app_ug/flow_filtering.html) application to learn how to use rte_flow.